# Where is this place? Windows 10 Wallpaper

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth

Looks like this is a middle east city. I am curious to know where. Windows does not give any info.
[image]

Comment: Can anybody comment why these wallpapers/lock screens do usually not reveal this information?

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager\LocalState\Assets, the lock screen spotlight images are stored here, so if you wanna see one copy and paste the largest size file and paste it as a .jpg. If the image properties contains the details it should show up :)

Comment: @stephanmg They do. When the screen is locked you get a "Like what you see?" hover in the top right which gives you photo details and copyright as well as the like / don't like buttons, and there's generally one or two more links on the screen that take you to a relevant Bing search after logging in.

Comment: Right click over the above image, "Search on Google Images", [_et voila_](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiv35Mk0uvvb268I-1I94gmMmIa1kXbgB673ENYeX3i4fGCW7X0DZJPSx_11SCom1bZ7bz5SWi3ggjJNUFXbASoRIURfeAO2LH4WbAY88VKIfNY6X3_1VOrsheUpIFRw_19zf3ykQXPdLI_1XNkAbBdHYDse8b94L--35jq3hVth-G9nCQtZaCM7hx8-i6FUTodSgHn_1GoDGjEd48lZlHl7N6w-Xzf5lsgR66h_1q12jfNIJgjKnW-tAsBiPWmmK2WiRbkKMY2EjqEiXU_1SloegQAZJGT3aRpuXviQKbt4w5wKX1H7EiRXDHnN6PPMadDd280BrZW2FJ1_1eb8DonMKRr_1mMvKRLkxrA), the answer below is confirmed :)

Comment: I see. Well I would still like a caption at the bottom.

Comment: They don't always show the "like what you see" link. I think it depends on the state of your internet connection/wifi.

Comment: @stephanmg if they added the caption you would be less inclined to click through to opening the page in Edge and viewing the content served by Bing.  (and yes, it's annoying)

Comment: I think whether the "like what you see?" shows up depends on the operating system too.

Comment: @stephanmg because its Microsoft. Honestly, I'd like to know what's their strategy for choosing in which language they show the description, when they show them, because it seems not to be the system language.

Comment: My amazon TVs also do not display the information per default. Have to set the options manually. I mean it's fine I just feel it should be the other way around.

Comment: Occasionally they do not show 'like what you see'. This is one of them. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 15):

This place is **Göreme**. A town in the Cappadocia region of central Turkey.

The best way to search for an image is to use the google image search.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Don't forget to try [Google Image Search / Lens](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) first. Results searching with your image:

[image]

First result: [Göreme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6reme).

Comment: Out of curiosity, are these screenshots taken on a pre-Truetype Windows 3.0 instance?

Comment: @magma  [Some fonts are difficult to read in Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera, while MSIE works fine](https://superuser.com/q/1293265/116475)